# Compare the percentages of two different sample sizes

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, standard-deviation, standardization

I would like to know the best way to compare and report the percentages from two samples. Last year's sample size had a total of 489 respondents and 74 participants chose item A; this year, the sample size is 503 and 105 participants chose item A.

For e.g.,

last year %: 74/489x100 = 15.13%

This year %: 105/503x100 = 20.87%

Since the total number of respondents is not the same in each group, can we report that last year, 15.13% of individuals chose item A whereas this year, 20.87% chose the same item A and we can see an increase of approxinmately 5%.

In addition, is there a statistical test that we need to run to compare if the % difference is statistically significant or not?

Please advise.

Comment: You can find literally hundreds of answers here on CV if you can guess the right keywords.  Search for [test of proportions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=test+of+proportions).  Since there are so many hits, [here is a refined search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=test+of+proportions+score%3A5+binomial).